# MAPS & Animation in R

Tags: r, animation, maps, aesthetics

Trying to do similar to this: [How the Ghana Floods animation was created](https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-the-ghana-floods-animation-was-created/)

My code below

```
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
#devtools::install_github("dgrtwo/gganimate")

library(readxl)

s_data <- read_excel("объекты.xls")
head(s_data)

p <- ggmap(get_map(c(32.10399,49.04548), zoom = 5))
p+geom_point(data = s_data, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, size=channels_contracted, cumulative = TRUE, frame = year), alpha=0.5)+ labs(title = "Objects until 2016 \n")
gganimate(p, outfile = "outfile11.gif", convert = "gm convert", ani.width = 700, title_frame = TRUE)
```

When trying to get points on the map - I have some warnings about unknown aesthetics (cumulative, frame). Then when I try to animate the result - I just got crash - see the code output below.

```
> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: cumulative, frame Warning
> message: Removed 11 rows containing missing values (geom_point). 
> > 
> > gganimate(p, outfile = "outfile11.gif", convert = "gm convert", ani.width = 700, title_frame = TRUE) Error in gganimate(p, outfile =
> "outfile11.gif", convert = "gm convert",  :    No frame aesthetic
> found; cannot create animation
```

What is the problem and how can i fix it?

If it's important - WindowsX64... So I think there will be some difficulties with the animations, ImageMagock and so on...

UPDATE: THE FIX was found with the help of @lukeA
It seems some warnings that happened during the work of a script crashed the animation generation.

Working solution:

```
    library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
library(readxl)
library(animation)
#s_data <- read_excel("C:/Users/fire/OneDrive/Документы/AMICO_WORK/current/объекты.xls")

channels_contracted=c(10,20,30,40,50,70,10,1)
year=c(1999,1999,2000,2000,2001,2002,2003,2003)
latitude=c(44.61217,46.97676,46.66602,46.51235,46.77762, 41.00222, 46.51235,46.77762)
longitude=c(30.72798,30.71394, 31.94281, 30.70631, 33.47262, 29.90559, 30.71394, 30.71775)
type=c("ASZ", "AGS", "ASZ", "AGS", "GNS", "GNS1", "GNS1", "AGS")
df = data.frame(channels_contracted, year, latitude, longitude, type) 

p <- ggmap(get_map(c(32.10399,49.04548), zoom = 5))

suppressWarnings(p <- p + geom_point(aes(longitude,latitude,frame=year,cumulative=FALSE, size = channels_contracted, color = type), df, alpha=0.3))

ani.options(interval=2)
gganimate(p)
```

Comment: Well, _" No frame aesthetic"_ arises due to `p` not having a frame aesthetic. Maybe reassign like `p <- p+geom_point......`? Or `gganimate(last_plot(), ......`?

Comment: well, maybe i didn't understand the logic... the frame and cumulative parameters are set in this code. But R gives that these parameters are unknown...

The output for reasigning is similar:
> p<-p+geom_point(data = data_1994, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, size=channels_contracted, cumulative = TRUE, frame = year), alpha=0.5)+ labs(caption="1994")
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: cumulative, frame

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example, which should be reproducible:

```
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
p <- ggmap(get_map(c(32.10399,49.04548), zoom = 5))
df <- data.frame(lon=seq(20,45,length.out=10), lat=seq(40,55,length.out=10),year=2001:2010)
suppressWarnings(p <- p + geom_point(aes(lon,lat,frame=year),df,color="red",size=5))
gganimate(p, width=2, height=2)
```

[image]

Comment: your code is reproducible... But what is wrong with my then? :) maybe the difference is in the types of the data?
`> class(s_data)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
> class(df)
[1] "data.frame"
> unique(s_data$year)
 [1] 1994 1995 1997 1998 2000 2001 2002 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014
[19] 2015 2016
> `

Comment: We could examime it if you edit your post and make your example reproducible (copy-paste-run able like mine). You can use `dput(s_data)` to share your data, or create some dummy data. Besides that, `gganimate` will grab the ignored `frame` aesthetic automatically, so ignore the warning. I dunno about `cumulative`.

Comment: just edited my question. Thank's a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of lukeA

```
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
library(readxl)
library(animation)
#s_data <- read_excel("C:/Users/fire/OneDrive/Документы/AMICO_WORK/current/объекты.xls")

channels_contracted=c(10,20,30,40,50,70,10,1)
year=c(1999,1999,2000,2000,2001,2002,2003,2003)
latitude=c(44.61217,46.97676,46.66602,46.51235,46.77762, 41.00222, 46.51235,46.77762)
longitude=c(30.72798,30.71394, 31.94281, 30.70631, 33.47262, 29.90559, 30.71394, 30.71775)
type=c("ASZ", "AGS", "ASZ", "AGS", "GNS", "GNS1", "GNS1", "AGS")
df = data.frame(channels_contracted, year, latitude, longitude, type) 

p <- ggmap(get_map(c(32.10399,49.04548), zoom = 5))

suppressWarnings(p <- p + geom_point(aes(longitude,latitude,frame=year,cumulative=FALSE, size = channels_contracted, color = type), df, alpha=0.3))

ani.options(interval=2)
gganimate(p)
```